# AsyncTask is throwing an InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, android

I have a simple Activity that uses an AsyncTask

```
EditText txt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectNetwork().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public void connectToNetwork(View view)
{
    String address = "https://www.google.com";
        new DownloadWebpageText().execute(address);

}
private class DownloadWebpageText extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
      {
       return params[0] + ",Some thing";

      }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result)
      {
       txt.setText(result); //this is an EditText

      }

}
```

I simplified the code for brevity ,however it is throwing InvocationTargetException and not executing onPostExecute method.I am not able to understand anything while debugging.   Any help?

Logcat errors:

```
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at myApp.src.MyAppActivity$DownloadWebpageText.onPostExecute(MyAppActivity.java:162)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at myApp.src.MyAppActivity$DownloadWebpageText.onPostExecute(MyAppActivity.java:1)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-08 00:16:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(537):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you need to set the content view and then lookup the view?

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given where your `NullPointerException` is coming from (`onPostExecute()`), `txt` apparently is `null`.

Comment: but it is initialized at onCreate

Comment: Lets do a quick check: `if(txt != null){txt.setText(result);}else{System.out.println("OOOPS I made a mistake!");}`

Comment: @Krroae27 I agree, but as you can see, I assigned the EditText to the variable txt.I there any life cycle trick?

Comment: @sleimanjneidi: The correct answer is Matt Wolfe's -- you must call `setContentView()` before trying to use `findViewById()`.